# TabControl for .NET MAUI

Tags: android, .net, maui

Is there a TabControl for .NET MAUI? I'm trying to use a part of my page to display multiple things. At the top there are general labels and buttons and below that I need different tabs to display data in different ways, or different events. The TabControl must not extend to the entire page. But I cannot find anything like a simple TabControl (from WPF or similar) for MAUI. Does it exist today? Or will I have to build it myself like I would have to do in HTML?

I'm not at all interested in any commercial or otherwise huge third-party libraries. I have my share of experiences with them and want to stay with the stock possibilities for a start.

Comment: [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinmutlow/92d033938dcede62b49980fbb0c6676f) that extends a ContentView to be a Tab bar. I haven’t used it, but that is a good approach to use, since you don’t want a full page. A ContentView can be used inside any layout.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a simple use case, then you can just use the TabBar that comes with the default MAUI Shell:

1. Create a new MAUI app using the default template
2. In your AppShell.xaml add the following:

```xml
<TabBar>
  <Tab>
    <ShellContent>
       ...
    </ShellContent>
  </Tab>
  <Tab>
    <ShellContent>
       ...
    </ShellContent>
  </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs

Alternatively, you can also use a TabbedPage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage

For more advanced scenarios, you'll need to use third party components. You could check out Uranium UI Kit for this: https://enisn-projects.io/docs/en/uranium/latest/themes/material/components/TabView